# What could be causing exit code 3221225477 with Python and OpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5

I have a script that I can confirm runs on other people's computers, but not on mine. Instead, it gives this error code:

```
[Finished in 6.1s with exit code 3221225477]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\PythonProjects\ClimatesProject\OpenGlTest.py"]
[dir: D:\PythonProjects\ClimatesProject]
[path: my path variable, I don't know how safe posting that is]
```

The code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageQt
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QOpenGLVersionProfile
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QOpenGLWidget, QWidget

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.glWidget = GLWidget()
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("SPHERE")

class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.object = 0
        self.xRot = 0
        self.yRot = 0
        self.zRot = 0

        self.lastPos = QPoint()

        self.main = QColor.fromCmykF(0.40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.clear = QColor.fromCmykF(0.39, 0.39, 0.0, 0.0)

        self.img = Image.open("BWTopoMidSqr.bmp")
        #self.img = Image.open("worldmap1.bmp")
        self.mapWidth, self.mapHeight = self.img.size
        pgImData = np.asarray(self.img)
        self.inputMapFile = np.flipud(pgImData)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(400, 400)

    def setXRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.xRot:
            self.xRot = angle
            self.update()

    def setYRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.yRot:
            self.yRot = angle
            self.update()

    def setZRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.zRot:
            self.zRot = angle
            self.update()

    def initializeGL(self):
        version_profile = QOpenGLVersionProfile()
        version_profile.setVersion(2, 0)
        self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions(version_profile)
        self.gl.initializeOpenGLFunctions()

        self.setClearColor(self.clear.darker())
        self.object = self.makeObject()
        self.gl.glShadeModel(self.gl.GL_SMOOTH)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_CULL_FACE)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_LIGHTING)
        self.gl.glLightModelfv(self.gl.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, [0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0])
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
        self.gl.glColorMaterial(self.gl.GL_FRONT, self.gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)
        
        self.gl.glActiveTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE0)
        self.text_obj = self.gl.glGenTextures(1)
        self.gl.glBindTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.text_obj)
        self.gl.glPixelStorei(self.gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
        self.gl.glTexImage2D(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, self.gl.GL_RGB, self.mapWidth, self.mapHeight, 0, self.gl.GL_RGB, self.gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.inputMapFile.tobytes())
        self.gl.glPixelStorei(self.gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4)
        self.gl.glTexParameterf(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, self.gl.GL_LINEAR)
        self.gl.glTexParameterf(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, self.gl.GL_LINEAR)
        
    def paintGL(self):
        self.gl.glClear(self.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | self.gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D) 
        self.gl.glBindTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.text_obj)
        self.gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
        self.gl.glCallList(self.object)
        
    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        if side < 0:
            return

        self.gl.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side,
                side)

        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glOrtho(-0.5, +0.5, +0.5, -0.5, 4.0, 15.0)
        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_MODELVIEW)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        dx = event.x() - self.lastPos.x()
        dy = event.y() - self.lastPos.y()

        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setYRotation(self.yRot + 8 * dx)
        elif event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setZRotation(self.zRot + 8 * dx)

        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def makeObject(self):
        genList = self.gl.glGenLists(1)
        self.gl.glNewList(genList, self.gl.GL_COMPILE)
        self.gl.glBegin(self.gl.GL_TRIANGLES)

        UResolution = 18
        VResolution = 36
        r = 0.3
        startU = 0
        startV = 0
        endU = math.pi * 2
        endV = math.pi
        stepU = (endU-startU)/UResolution # step size between U-points on the grid
        stepV = (endV-startV)/VResolution # step size between V-points on the grid
        for i in range(UResolution):  # U-points
            for j in range(VResolution):  # V-points
                u = i*stepU+startU
                v = j*stepV+startV
                un = endU if (i+1==UResolution) else (i+1)*stepU+startU
                vn = endV if (j+1==VResolution) else (j+1)*stepV+startV

                p0 = [ math.cos(u)*math.sin(v)*r, math.cos(v)*r, math.sin(u)*math.sin(v)*r ]
                p1 = [ math.cos(u)*math.sin(vn)*r, math.cos(vn)*r, math.sin(u)*math.sin(vn)*r ] 
                p2 = [ math.cos(un)*math.sin(v)*r, math.cos(v)*r, math.sin(un)*math.sin(v)*r ]
                p3 = [ math.cos(un)*math.sin(vn)*r, math.cos(vn)*r, math.sin(un)*math.sin(vn)*r ]

                t0 = [i/UResolution, 1-j/VResolution]
                t1 = [i/UResolution, 1-(j+1)/VResolution]
                t2 = [(i+1)/UResolution, 1-j/VResolution]
                t3 = [(i+1)/UResolution, 1-(j+1)/VResolution]

                # Output the first triangle of this grid square
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t0)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p0)
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t2)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p2)
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t1)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p1)

                # Output the other triangle of this grid square
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t3)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p3)
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t1)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p1)
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t2)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p2)

        self.gl.glEnd()
        self.gl.glEndList()

        return genList

    def normalizeAngle(self, angle):
        while angle < 0:
            angle += 360 * 16
        while angle > 360 * 16:
            angle -= 360 * 16
        return angle

    def setClearColor(self, c):
        self.gl.glClearColor(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())

    def setColor(self, c):
        self.gl.glColor4f(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's the product of another question I asked on StackOverflow. The person giving the code assured me it worked on their computer, but neither computer I have access to works. They either give the above error or no output (it seems random which one they pick).

I've already tried reinstalling python and all packages.
Interestingly, commenting out line 84 (`self.gl.glTexImage2D(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D...`) gives an output, but without the wanted texture.

Possibly helpful information (will be added to as others suggest):

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Python 3.9.0
- PyQt5 5.15.2
- numpy 1.19.3
- PIL 8.0.1
- I generally use Sublime Text to run the code, but using a command doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: `0xC0000005` eh?  You sure that `Image.open()` is succeeding?

Comment: Well, I can run `print(self.img.size)` in the next line and it prints an expected answer (in this case `(1024, 1024)`

Comment: I've tested your code again and it works fine. Try to use an absolut file path (just for debugging): `Image.open(r"D:\PythonProjects\ClimatesProject\BWTopoMidSqr.bmp")`

Comment: Made the change. Unfortunately, it hasn't fixed the issue

Comment: How are you running the script? If you ran it on an IDE, just try with the command prompt, it is usually more verbose. Btw, it seems more an OpenGL related issue, is the other person running Windows too? Have you tried other simpler OpenGL examples?

Comment: @musicamante I'm the other person. Yes I use windows and the most recent versions of all required packages

Comment: Simpler OpenGL examples work. If I don't try texturing the sphere, this code runs fine. I'm running OpenGL version 4.6. Would that matter?

Comment: I have sometimes found that texturing in OpenGL can fail if you don't explicitly set the wrap mode for S and T. Not sure it will fix the problem, but it can't hurt to try